# How to use reflection to create a class in app_code?

Tags: asp.net, reflection

I have a class Customer in app_code folder in asp.net web site, how can I create an instance using reflection, for example using Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName)? Because the app_code is dynamically compiled, I don't know the assembly in design time?

Thanks
Fred

The question is should be how get a full name of type in design time, I want to put it in web.config. I have ConfigSection type, it is in app_code folder, I need to declare it in configSection. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use "App_Code" or  "__Code" as the assembly name in the web.config

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) to get a reference to the current assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem in this way:

```
Type[] appCodeTypes = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_Code").GetTypes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GetType().Assembly if you know that it will be the same assembly as your currently executing code.